# Issues with userdefaults usage swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I just started learning Swift so the level of this question may be obvious enough for you, however, I simply can't understand what to do.

I "created" a simple app which allows you to add logs of your day. Each cell stores the time you added, a custom icon that changes depending on the time, and, the log text itself (simple text).

Everything works fine. But, as I didn't know about the "Userdefaults" stuff, the clock resets every time I kill the app.

I read many articles about Userdefaults but I have no idea what to do to keep saving my data even when I kill the app.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
class ToDoItem: NSObject, NSCoding {


var title: String
var date: String
var type: String!

public init(title: String, date: String, type: String) {

    self.title = title
    self.date = date
    self.type = type

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    // Try to unserialize the "title" variable
    if let title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? String
    {
        self.title = title
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        self.date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

        let hour = NSCalendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
        var tempType = ""
        switch hour {
        case 5..<9: tempType = "morning_1"
        case 6..<12: tempType = "morning_2"
        case 12: tempType = "noon_1"
        case 13..<16: tempType = "afternoon_1"
        case 16..<20: tempType = "dusk_1"
        case 20..<23: tempType = "evening_1"
        case 23..<00: tempType = "midnight_1"
        default: tempType = "morning_1"


        }

        self.type = tempType

    }



    else
    {
        // There were no objects encoded with the key "title",
        // so that's an error.
        return nil
    }

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "title")

}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    // Store the objects into the coder object
    aCoder.encode(self.title, forKey: "title")

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(false, forKey: "title")


}
```

}

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == ToDoItem
{
    // Builds the persistence URL. This is a location inside
    // the "Application Support" directory for the App.
    private static func persistencePath() -> URL?
    {
        let url = try? FileManager.default.url(
            for: .applicationSupportDirectory,
            in: .userDomainMask,
            appropriateFor: nil,
            create: true)

        return url?.appendingPathComponent("todoitems.bin")
    }

    // Write the array to persistence
    func writeToPersistence() throws
    {
        if let url = Self.persistencePath(), let array = self as? NSArray
        {
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array)
            try data.write(to: url)
        }
        else
        {
            throw NSError(domain: "com.example.MyToDo", code: 10, userInfo: nil)
        }
    }

    // Read the array from persistence
    static func readFromPersistence() throws -> [ToDoItem]
    {
        if let url = persistencePath(), let data = (try Data(contentsOf: url) as Data?)
        {
            if let array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [ToDoItem]
            {
                return array
            }
            else
            {
                throw NSError(domain: "com.example.MyToDo", code: 11, userInfo: nil)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw NSError(domain: "com.example.MyToDo", code: 12, userInfo: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me or at least point what I have to do? thank you!

Comment: What about a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=user+defaults+swift) ?

Comment: as I told you I did. I don't understand what to do with the code. Useful comments are welcome tho! :-)

Comment: ... or a [Stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsuserdefaults) ? By the way, what do the `readFrom-` / `writeToPersistence` functions do?

Comment: I did. I get errors when I do stuff suggested. Like 

 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(false, forKey: "title")

Comment: Then post the code you've tried and that doesn't work. Your implementation of the tableview here is irrelevant to the question asked.

Comment: thanks, updated the code. Thought it would be useful to see the entire class thing.

Comment: Well, this is perfectly valid code. *What* doesn't work ?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand. Simply doesn't work. If I kill the app, the clock resets anyway. All data are saved, except the clock. every cell gets the actual date, not the date it was added.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Extract from your project all the code related to persistence (read and write), explain in detail what you're trying to do (what *the clock* is) and what happens instead. "*It* doesn't work" is never going to get you and answer.

Comment: Updated again. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: ,I can't find where do you load data from defaults?

Comment: Again with the tableview implementation... The only code that matters here is the implementation of `ToDoItem`, `writeToPersistence` and `readFromPersistence` (and maybe `configureCell(todo:)`) and this is the code you insist on not showing...

Comment: code is updated. In fact, the "let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "title")" doesn't return error anymore, but still resets the clock.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` which is a different mechanism than `UserDefaults`. Both are perfectly valid, but you have to pick one, they don't work together.

Here you are archiving and unarchiving an array of `ToDoItem`. For this to work, `ToDoItem` needs to be archivable, meaning it must implement the `NSCoding` protocol, which is:

```
public protocol NSCoding {
    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
    public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) // NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
}
```

All the properties that you want to save must be added to/extracted from the `NSCoder` object. Here is an example:

```
class ToDoItem: NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var title: String
    var date: Date

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        guard let title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let date = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "date") as? Date else {
            return nil
        }
        self.title = title
        self.date = date
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
    {
        aCoder.encode(self.title, forKey: "title")
        aCoder.encode(self.date, forKey: "date")
    }
}
```